# TypeError: 'tuple' object does not support item assignment np.append()

Tags: python-3.x, numpy, append, tuples

l would like to add the fifth element of list_2 to list_1 such that :

```
      type(list_1)
      Out[168]: numpy.ndarray
      list_1.shape
      Out[170]: (123,)
      type(list_2[4])
      numpy.int64
```

list_1 contains the following elements :

> array([ 0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  1,  1,  1,  1,  1,  1,  1,  1,  2,
>   2,
>               2,  2,  2,  2,  2,  2,  3,  3,  3,  3,  3,  3,  3,  3,  4,  4,  4,
>               4,  4,  4,  4,  4,  5,  5,  5,  5,  5,  5,  5,  5,  6,  6,  6,  6,
>               6,  6,  6,  6,  7,  7,  7,  7,  7,  7,  7,  7,  8,  8,  8,  8,  8,
>               8,  8,  8,  8,  9,  9,  9,  9,  9,  9,  9,  9,  9, 10, 10, 10, 10,
>              10, 10, 10, 10, 10, 10, 11, 11, 11, 11, 11, 11, 11, 11, 11, 11, 12,
>              12, 12, 12, 12, 12, 12, 12, 12, 12, 13, 13, 13, 13, 13, 13, 13, 13,
>              13, 13, 13, 13])

when l make

```
np.Append(list_1,list_2[4]) # list_2[4]=78
```

The element is indeed added

> array([ 0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  1,  1,  1,  1,  1,  1,  1,  1, 
>   2,  2,
>               2,  2,  2,  2,  2,  2,  3,  3,  3,  3,  3,  3,  3,  3,  4,  4,  4,
>               4,  4,  4,  4,  4,  5,  5,  5,  5,  5,  5,  5,  5,  6,  6,  6,  6,
>               6,  6,  6,  6,  7,  7,  7,  7,  7,  7,  7,  7,  8,  8,  8,  8,  8,
>               8,  8,  8,  8,  9,  9,  9,  9,  9,  9,  9,  9,  9, 10, 10, 10, 10,
>              10, 10, 10, 10, 10, 10, 11, 11, 11, 11, 11, 11, 11, 11, 11, 11, 12,
>              12, 12, 12, 12, 12, 12, 12, 12, 12, 13, 13, 13, 13, 13, 13, 13, 13,
>              13, 13, 13, 13,78])

However , the shape of list_1 remains the same. We are supposed to get 124 element rather than

```
list_1.shape
Out[175]: (123,)
```

Even if indeed the updated list_1 contains 124 elements. What is wrong  with my implementation ?

2) What l tried to solve that ?
l did an assignment as follow :

```
list_1=np.append(list_1,list_2[4])
```

l got the following error :

```
TypeError: 'tuple' object does not support item assignment
```

**Edit1**

list_1=np.append(list_1,list_2[4]) # works well

However : 
it fails in my real example

```
v_coordinates[1][127][0]=np.append(v_coordinates[1][127][0],v_coordinates[1][14][0][3])# Here l get the error TypeError: 'tuple' object does not support item assignment
```

But : assign to it a new variable it works.

```
 new_var=np.append(v_coordinates[1][127][0],v_coordinates[1][14][0][3])
```

How can l use append by preserving the actual assignment `v_coordinates[1][127][0]` needed for later process ?

Thank you

Comment: tuples are immutable and it is taking list_1 as tuple

Comment: So how can l update my list_1 ?

Comment: From the [docs](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.append.html): "Note that `append` does not occur in-place." - instead it returns the new array, which you can assign to `list_1` again: `list_1 = np.append(list_1, list_2[4])`

Comment: @Jeronimo this is what l've done here list_1=np.append(list_1,list_2[4]) but l got TypeError: 'tuple' object does not support item assignment

Comment: Ok, this I can't reproduce. It gives me the new array as expected (numpy 1.9.2, CPython 3.4 on Windows). But if your first step worked, as you said, the assignment later on should work, too.

Comment: l'm using ubuntu. Python3.6 and nupmy 1.13.1

Comment: @Jeronimo l identified the problem. Please see my update (EDIT 1)

Comment: In this case, if you don't want to rebuild the whole tuple, you could use [ndarray.resize](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-1.13.0/reference/generated/numpy.ndarray.resize.html#numpy.ndarray.resize) to reshape the array in-place, then assign the new value to the new slot.
Another idea would be to replace your tuple with a (mutable) list, if that's possible with the rest of your code.

Comment: @Jeronimo, thank you for your answer. Do do mind make a line of code to see how you build that to be sure l understand your solution. Thanks again